# Created Validation rule to ensure product has been added before a certain stage, but can't add products

Tags: validation, validation-rule

Created Validation rule (below) to ensure product(s) has been added before a certain stage, but can't add products to an already created opportunity that is beyond that stage.  When I go to add a product the validation rule triggers and brings me back to the opportunity, essentially locking that opportunity.  How do I fix it where they can't progress the opportunity to a stage but they can add a product?

```
AND( 
ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Customer Webinar Completed, Cultivate") || 
ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Customer Webinar Completed, Interest") || 
ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Proposal Accepted") || 
ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Proposal/Price Quote") || 
ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Closed Won") || 
ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Proposal/Project Quoted"), 
HasOpportunityLineItem = FALSE, 
DATEVALUE( CreatedDate )<>TODAY(), 
RecordType.Id = '01234000000XXXX' || 
RecordType.Id = '01234000000XXXX' || 
RecordType.Id = '01234000000XXXX' || 
RecordType.Id = '01234000000XXXX' || 
RecordType.Id = '01234000000XXXX' 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe based on your description that what you need is to add an

```
ISCHANGED(StageName)
```

check within your outermost `AND()`.

This will result in your validation rule only being evaluated when the Stage of the Opportunity is updated; other changes to the record won't trigger it at all.

Comment: Thanks David, this works great, I'll try and come up with something more difficult next time.